# Gemfile not found using Cron job with Capistrano 3 and whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, capistrano3, whenever

Cron Job Working Fine on my pc. But when i deploy it to the server using capistrano.
The cron.log file show that it is looking for that release which is not present on server how can i resolve this problem. any idea...?

```
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:22:in `build': /home/deployer/apps/production_app/releases/20140906112257/Gemfile not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
    from
```

When i run crontab -e command its show to the correct release

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: production_app
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deployer/apps/production_app/releases/20150504102922 && bin/rails runner -e production '\''Vehicle.check_not_responding'\'' >> /home/deployer/apps/production_app/releases/20150504102922/log/cron.log 2>&1'

* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deployer/apps/production_app/releases/20150504102922 && bin/rails runner -e production '\''SmsDetail.send_sms'\'' >> /home/deployer/apps/production_app/releases/20150504102922/log/cron.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: production_app
```

How i can fix this problem...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago. turns out the variable BUNDLE_GEMFILE isn't defined when cron tries to run the tasks. so you would need the following in your `schedule.rb`:

```
env :BUNDLE_GEMFILE, ENV["/#{path}/Gemfile"]
```

or

```
env :BUNDLE_GEMFILE, ENV["/home/deployer/apps/production_app/current/Gemfile"]
```

Let me know what helps in your case.